# ¿Cómo usar la función kbhit() repetidas veces?

Tags: c++

Éste es mi código con la clase para una Pistola y una Bala, donde hay definidas funciones para mover, dibujar y borrar cada una de ellas.

El problema está en el uso de la función `kbhit()`, que la llamo desde 2 partes diferentes del código:

1. Para hacer mover el arma
2. Para disparar

Así como tengo el código, no me funciona cuando la intento usar para los disparos (comentado al final del código).

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pw;
    pw.X = x;
    pw.Y = y;
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, pw);
}
class Pistola{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Pistola(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y){}
    void pintar();
    void borrar();
    void mover();
    int getX(){return x;}
    int getY(){return y;}
};
void Pistola::pintar(){
    gotoxy(x,y);   printf("( )==:");
    gotoxy(x,y+1); printf("||");
}
void Pistola::borrar(){
    gotoxy(x,y);   printf("      ");
    gotoxy(x,y+1); printf("      ");
}
void Pistola::mover(){
if(kbhit()){                     // <--- Aca estoy usando para mover
    borrar();
    char tecla = getch();
    if(tecla == 'i') y--;
    if(tecla == 'k') y++;
    if(tecla == 'j') x--;
    if(tecla == 'l') x++;
    pintar();
    }
}

class Bala{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Bala(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y){}
    void pintar();
    void mover();
    void borrar();
    int getX(){return x;}
    int getY(){return y;}
};
void Bala::pintar(){
    gotoxy(x,y); printf("*");
}
void Bala::mover(){
    gotoxy(x,y); printf(" ");
    if( x < 70 ) x++;
    gotoxy(x,y); printf("*");
}
void Bala::borrar(){
     gotoxy(x,y); printf(" ");
}

int main()
{
Pistola arma(10,10);

bool game_over = false;

list<Bala*> B;
list<Bala*>::iterator it;

arma.pintar();

while( !game_over ){
    /// El problema esta en que si uso la funcion khbit() para hacer mover el armar, no me funcion cuando
    /// la intento usar para los disparos, si corta arma.mover() y lo pega justo antes de Sleep(30) notara
    /// que lo que funiona bien son los disparos y lo que falla es la funcion mover del arma.
    arma.mover();

    if( kbhit() ){               // <--- Aca estoy usando para disparar
        char tecla = getch();
        if( tecla == 'a'){
            B.push_back(new Bala(arma.getX()+7, arma.getY()));
        }
    }
    for( it = B.begin(); it != B.end(); it++){
        (*it)->mover();
        if( (*it)->getX() >= 70 ){
            (*it)->borrar();
            delete (*it);
            it = B.erase(it);
        }
    }

    Sleep(30);
}

return 0;
}
```

Por ejemplo, depurando, si se corta la llamada a `kbhit()` de `arma.mover()` y lo pega justo antes de `Sleep(30)`, cambiando el orden del bucle para que primero lea el disparo y luego el movimiento, notará que lo que funciona bien son los disparos y lo que falla es la función mover del arma.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo? ¿Cómo puedo usar la función `kbhit()` repetidas veces?

Comment: Cristian, edita tu pregunta para aclarar qué es lo que obtienes en este momento y cuál debería ser el resultado esperado. No está claro lo que quieres y tu pregunta puede ser cerrada por no cumplir con la política de calidad.

Comment: Votando para reabrir. Creo que estaba clara la pregunta, pero igual edité según lo que interpreté. De yapa, tiene 2 buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usar kbhit() y getch() no es la mejor elección para un juego, ya que ambas dependen del buffer de teclado.

Considera esto: cuando presionas una tecla y la dejas presionada, el driver del teclado primero envía una ocurrencia del caractér al buffer, si dejas presionada la tecla por mas de 250ms (eso es configurable, pero es el valor por defecto), comienza a enviar una ocurrencia del carácter de forma repetida cada 100ms.

Esto es un dolor de cabeza para un juego donde el tiempo siempre es crucial y es la razón por la cual el arma se mueve de la forma en que lo hace.

La solución de @Alvaro no toma en cuenta este problema, aunque podría solucionar el problema actual, no soluciona el problema mas importante: la forma que tomas la entrada de teclado.

El mejor enfoque es leer el estado de cada tecla (presionado, no presionado) por cada paso del bucle principal y establecer una variable que indique si la tecla esta presionada o no y con esto decidir que hacer. Hay que olvidarse de usar el buffer de entrada de teclado.

Es por esta razón que existen librerías como XInput, SDL y otras librerías similares.

He modificado un poco tu programa, primero he agregado una funciona llamada `isKeydown`. Esta función hace uso de [`GeyKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) para saber si la tecla esta o no presionada, es como una foto de la tecla, no usa el buffer de teclado. Esta es una forma simple de hacerlo, pero recuerda que hay librerías completas dedicadas a la entrada en directo.

```
bool isKeyDown(int vkey) {
    return GetKeyState(vkey) < 0;
}
```

Luego modifique la función `Pistola::mover` de la siguiente forma:

```
void Pistola::mover(){
    // ver lista completa de virtual keys en
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

    if(isKeyDown(0x49)){ // 'i',
        borrar();
        y--;
        pintar();
    } else
    if(isKeyDown(0x4B)){ // 'k',
        borrar();
        y++;
        pintar();
    } else
    if(isKeyDown(0x4A)){ // 'j',
        borrar();
        x--;
        pintar();
    } else
    if(isKeyDown(0x4C)){ // 'l',
        borrar();
        x++;
        pintar();
    }

}
```

Por ultimo modifique la parte donde disparas la bala.

```
if(isKeyDown(0x41)){ // 'a'
   B.push_back(new Bala(arma.getX()+7, arma.getY()));
}
```

Y este es el resultado... Como ves se comporta como un juego normal, donde al presionar una tecla responde de forma intuitiva.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: He usado `GetKeyState` pues veo que incluyes el archivo "windows.h", y asumo que lo estas desarrollando en windows. De querer portarlo a otra plataforma como esta función es propia de Windows no funcionara y deberá usarse alguna librería apropiada para la plataforma.

Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Como se sugiere en esta [pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721376/using-multiple-kbhit-in-a-loop), lo que puedes hacer es leer el valor de `kbhit()` y guardarlo en una variable que será lo que compruebas en ambas funciones, en lugar de leer `kbhit()` dos veces y perder el buffer con la tecla que fue pulsada.

Así lo que tendrías que hacer sería:

- Definir una nueva variable donde se guardará el valor de la tecla.
- Al principio del bucle comprueba si `kbhit()` devuelve algo:

  - Si sí devuelve algo (se pulsó una tecla): guarda su valor en la variable que creaste
  - Si no devuelve nada (no se pulsó tecla): asigna un valor por defecto a la variable (p.e.: '')
- Reemplaza en tu código las referencias a `kbhit()` y `getch()` y utiliza la variable que creaste en su lugar.

Así, podrías cambiar las cosas en el main (nota, no he probado el código, puede contener fallos):

```
int main()
{
  Pistola arma(10,10);
  char tecla = '';
  bool game_over = false;

  list<Bala*> B;
  list<Bala*>::iterator it;

  arma.pintar();

  while( !game_over ){
    ´
    if (kbhit()) {
      tecla = getch();
    } else {
      tecla = '';
    }

    arma.mover();

    if( tecla == 'a'){
      B.push_back(new Bala(arma.getX()+7, arma.getY()));
    }

    ...
```

Eso solucionaría el problema en el `main`, ahora para el método `mover` de la clase Arma, lo que podrías hacer es pasarle el valor de tecla como parámetro y comparar con ese valor:

```
void Pistola::mover(char tecla){
  if(tecla != ''){
    borrar();
    if(tecla == 'i') y--;
    if(tecla == 'k') y++;
    if(tecla == 'j') x--;
    if(tecla == 'l') x++;
    pintar();
  }
}

...

// y en el main, dentro del bucle, lo llamarías así
arma.mover(tecla);
```